# Cathie Wood "Bitcoin not suitable for ETFs" - why?

Tags: taxes, bitcoin-etf

Cathie Wood of ARK Invest is quoted in a [Bloomberg article](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2020-12-18/cathie-wood-sees-control-fight-ending-lifting-cloud-over-ark):

> Wood was a believer in Bitcoin, too, and it powered some of the early gains in her funds. But **after discovering an adverse tax rule, Ark decided it wasn’t appropriate for ETFs**. Bitcoin, which hit $20,000 this week for the first time, is a 7% position in certain Ark separate accounts. Wood said she remains “extremely bullish.”

Markup mine.

What is she talking about?